# Excel - Copying content from a cell to another ( with condition )

Tags: excel

i have a little issue with excel doing this
let's say i have 4 cells
A,B,C,D
A and C are just identifiers ( they have same text )
but not ordered i want to perform a function that copy cell D content to B if they had the same identifier ( A and C )
example :

```
A B C D 
something AsomethingA something CsomethingC
```

result :

```
A B C D
something CsomethingC something CsomethingC
```

i hope i didn't make it compliacted 
thank you guys in advance!

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but we do expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you have and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a question related to that code, and we'll try to help. Start with reading the Excel help for the `IF()` function.

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Add it to the question using the [edit] link (located below the tags), so it can be seen. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, i used Vlookup function
,here is it :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;$C$1:$D$2000;2;FALSE);"NO MATCH FOUND")
```

In my case i had 2000 cells, you can edit it however you want
,have a nice day!